# Segmenting .flac files with ffmpeg truncates audio but not file length

Tags: macos, twitter, ffmpeg, flac

I am trying to get Twitter spaces audio (.ts) files into a format I can easily edit, on OSX.

So far I was able to convert the files in bulk to .flac with this:

```
for i in *.ts;
do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
echo "$name"
ffmpeg -i "$i" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 41000 "${name}.flac"
done
```

That worked, and reduced the file sizes somewhat, but..
Because most of the files are around 7 hours long, my editor of choice cannot process that much audio in one file.

So I looked around and was able to find this command to segment the files into 3hr long sections.

```
ffmpeg -i space-1OdKrBealBqKX_0.flac -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10800 -c copy space-1OdKrBealBqKX_0__%03d.flac
```

This works, but each file contains as much empty / silent space at the end as the orginal file. That's going to be a problem for sharing with a team that will help edit these files, as each file has the original file's length and file size. There are a lot of files.
The audio segments and naming did work though.

How to truncate the actual length of the file to the audio segment?

Caveat: I am no expert on any of these matters, I just managed to google and get this far, so if someone knows and wants to provide working code that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does `-reset_timestamps 1` option help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLAC files contain metadata of stream duration. When streamcopying, ffmpeg cannot overwrite that metadata, so it is retained.

Your workaround is to segment in the original step.

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 -f segment -segment_time 10800 "${name}__%03d.flac"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Overall file size increased by 3x, but everything seems correct. There's no blank space.